# How do I get one distinct record per IP Address Per Day?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We are trying to limit voting by one IP address per day for some rock videos.  I have started with this query from another question on stack overflow.  However it is only return one vote per day when I need one vote per IP address per day.  How would I do this please?

```
;with cte as
(
  select
    *,
    row_number() over(partition by datediff(d, 0, created) order by created desc) as rn 
  from rock_vote
)
select cte.VideoId, cte.IPAddress, o.BandName, cte.Created
from cte  
inner join rock_video o on cte.videoId = o.videoid
where rn = 1
order by created desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;with cte as
(
  select
    *,
    row_number() over(partition by IPAddress, datediff(d, 0, created) 
    -------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^
    order by created desc) as rn 
  from rock_vote
)
select cte.VideoId, cte.IPAddress, o.BandName, cte.Created
from cte  
inner join rock_video AS o on cte.videoId = o.videoid
where cte.rn = 1
order by o.created desc;
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron.  Love the beaker avatar.